# How do I escape an opening square bracket in an ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have something like the following under properties for an application settings configuration:

```
"my_setting" : "[{width:1, height:2}]"
```

I want exactly the string contained in the value (including the square brackets) to appear on the application settings. Unfortunately, the opening square bracket indicates a function and the deployment throws me an exception due to it. How can I escape the beginning square bracket?

Comment: i think \ is used as escape character in arm templates, but i'm not sure it works for `[]`

Comment: Can't escape a bracket that way, unfortunately.

Comment: like i said... ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The escape sequence for ARM templates is the left bracket itself (i.e. just put two together)

```
"my_setting" : "[[{width:1, height:2}]"
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I escape the beginning square bracket?

We could use the [concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-array#concat) function  to avoid to using the special characters

```
"variables": {
   ...
    "left": "[",
    "right": "]",
    ...
  },
```

Please have a try to use following code. It works correctly on my side.

```
"my_setting": "[concat(variables('left'),'{width:1, height:2}',variables('right'))]",
```

Comment: Clever, thanks. It's a shame we have to go through this hacky route. The "left" variable also shows up as an irritating syntax error (but it works like a charm).